# Not able to resolve a leak detected by leaks tool. Can i ignore it?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks, objective-c++

I am not able to find a way to remove a leak detected by leaks tool.
Here is my problem...
I have a singleton object in my delegate which stores data on a global level. Now, I have a array of objects which i maintain here and add or modify it from controllers.
Below is a function which fills the objects and sets the above global array, 
Now, the highlighted lines(marked by //LEAK) are where the leaks tool tell me its a leak. I require this array for my session. I release the array at the end when i logout.
Should i be worried about this kind leak?

```
-(LayoutInfo *) fillLayout: (GDataXMLElement *) layoutElement {

        LayoutInfo *layout = [[LayoutInfo alloc] init];
        layout.dataTableCount = 0;
        layout.chartsCount = 0;
        NSArray *templateNameArr = [layoutElement elementsForName:@"TemplateName"];


        NSMutableArray *chartElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];   // LEAK 
        NSMutableArray *dtElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSArray *charts = [layoutElement elementsForName:@"chart"];     // LEAK 
        if (charts.count > 0) {
            for (GDataXMLElement *singleChart in charts) {
                chart *chartInfo = [[chart alloc] init];  // LEAK 
                layout.chartsCount = layout.chartsCount + 1;
                NSArray *imageName = [singleChart elementsForName:@"imageName"];
                if (imageName.count > 0) {
                    GDataXMLElement *imageNameStr = (GDataXMLElement *) [imageName objectAtIndex:0];
                    chartInfo.imageName = imageNameStr.stringValue; // LEAK 
                }           
                NSArray *imagePath = [singleChart elementsForName:@"imagePath"];
                if (imagePath.count > 0) {
                    GDataXMLElement *imagePathStr = (GDataXMLElement *) [imagePath objectAtIndex:0];
                    chartInfo.imagePath = imagePathStr.stringValue;  // LEAK 
                } 

                NSArray *imageFileName = [singleChart elementsForName:@"imageFileName"];
                if (imageFileName.count > 0) {
                    GDataXMLElement *imageFileNameStr = (GDataXMLElement *) [imageFileName objectAtIndex:0];
                    chartInfo.imageFileName = imageFileNameStr.stringValue;
                } 
                ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:chartInfo.imagePath]];
                [request setDownloadDestinationPath:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] 
                                                     stringByAppendingPathComponent:chartInfo.imageFileName]];

                [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(fillLayout_requestDone:)];
                [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(fillLayout_requestWentWrong:)];
                [request startSynchronous];

                NSString *imagePath1 = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:chartInfo.imageFileName];
                if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath1]) {
                    NSLog(@" --- IMAGE SAVED -- %@", imagePath1);
                }
                [chartElements addObject:chartInfo];
            } //for
            layout.chartElement = chartElements;   // THIS IS WHERE I ASSIGN THE GLOBAL ARRAY
            //[chartElements release];
        } 
        return layout;
    }
```

Comment: How is `chartElement` declared in `LayoutInfo `?

Comment: `layout.chartElement` - what kind of property is `chartElement` from layout? if it's `retain` or `copy` you should release `chartElements` (decomment commented line). If it's `assign` you'll have to release `layout.chartElements` (although this is unsafe if you assign it from other places as well). `dtElements` doesn't seem to be used and leaks, either remove the line containing it, or if you wish to use it remember to release it afterwards.

Comment: @property(assign)NSMutableArray *chartElement;

Comment: I have released dtElements. Thanks. But again, I will be using layout.chartElement in my session. Since i might need it, releasing it now is not helping. Can i ignore this leak when i submit? This is the only leak i have now.

Comment: Make chartElements a retain property, and release the local variable after `layout.chartElements = chartElements`. release doesn't mean the object is deleted. It just means one owner is done with it. When all owners are done with it, it will be deleted. Also release chartElements in your dealloc (though if it's a singleton it might never be called, but I think leaks won't complain about that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(LayoutInfo *) fillLayout: (GDataXMLElement *) layoutElement {

    LayoutInfo *layout = [[LayoutInfo alloc] init];
    layout.dataTableCount = 0;
    layout.chartsCount = 0;
    NSArray *templateNameArr = [layoutElement elementsForName:@"TemplateName"];


    NSMutableArray *chartElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];   // LEAK 
    //NSMutableArray *dtElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *charts = [layoutElement elementsForName:@"chart"];     // LEAK 
    if (charts.count > 0) {
        for (GDataXMLElement *singleChart in charts) {
            chart *chartInfo = [[chart alloc] init];  // LEAK 
            layout.chartsCount = layout.chartsCount + 1;
            NSArray *imageName = [singleChart elementsForName:@"imageName"];
            if (imageName.count > 0) {
                GDataXMLElement *imageNameStr = (GDataXMLElement *) [imageName objectAtIndex:0];
                chartInfo.imageName = imageNameStr.stringValue; // LEAK 
            }           
            NSArray *imagePath = [singleChart elementsForName:@"imagePath"];
            if (imagePath.count > 0) {
                GDataXMLElement *imagePathStr = (GDataXMLElement *) [imagePath objectAtIndex:0];
                chartInfo.imagePath = imagePathStr.stringValue;  // LEAK 
            } 

            NSArray *imageFileName = [singleChart elementsForName:@"imageFileName"];
            if (imageFileName.count > 0) {
                GDataXMLElement *imageFileNameStr = (GDataXMLElement *) [imageFileName objectAtIndex:0];
                chartInfo.imageFileName = imageFileNameStr.stringValue;
            } 
            ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:chartInfo.imagePath]];
            [request setDownloadDestinationPath:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] 
                                                 stringByAppendingPathComponent:chartInfo.imageFileName]];

            [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(fillLayout_requestDone:)];
            [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(fillLayout_requestWentWrong:)];
            [request startSynchronous];

            NSString *imagePath1 = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:chartInfo.imageFileName];
            if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath1]) {
                NSLog(@" --- IMAGE SAVED -- %@", imagePath1);
            }
            [chartElements addObject:chartInfo];
            [chartInfo release];                   // it's retained in chartElements until removed, or until chartElements is deallocced
        } //for
        if(layout.charElement){
            [layout.charElement release];     // you should however consider in making charElement property as retain;
            layout.charElement = nil;         // this isn't required here (since you're assigning it a new value), but you should usually set it to nil after a release to prevent EXC_BADACCESS
        }
        layout.chartElement = chartElements;   // THIS IS WHERE I ASSIGN THE GLOBAL ARRAY
        //[chartElements release];
    } 
    return [layout autorelease];   // in case you don't want it autoreleased you should call your method something like: createFilledLayout ('create' is usually used so anyone that uses the method knows it's responsible for releasing the return value)
}
```

you should have a look at [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)

Comment: Yes, I think I should do that.